# Large Image Compositing on iOS in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, image

Although I understand the theory behind image compositing, I haven't dealt much with hardware acceleration and I'm running into implementation issues on iOS (9.2, iPhone 6S). My project is to sequentially composite a large number (20, all the way to hundreds) of large images (12 megapixel) on top of each other at decreasing opacities, and I'm looking for advice as to the best framework or technique. I know there must be a good, hardware accelerated, destructive compositing tool capable of handling large files on iOS, because I can perform this task in Safari in an HTML Canvas tag, and load this page in Safari on the iPhone at nearly the same blazing speed.

This can be a destructive compositing task, like painting in Canvas, so I shouldn't have memory issues as the phone will only have to store the current result up to that point. Ideally, I'd like floating point pixel components, and I'd also like to be able to see the progress on screen.

Core Image has filters that seem great, but they are intended to operate losslessly on one or two pictures and return one result. I can feed that result into the filter again with the next image, and so on, but since the filter doesn't render immediately, this chaining of filters runs me out of memory after about 60 images. Rendering to a Core Graphics image object and reading back in as a Core Image object after each filter doesn't help either, as that overloads the memory even faster.

Looking at the documentation, there are a number of other ways for iOS to leverage the GPU - CALayers being a prime example. But I'm unclear if that handles pictures larger than the screen, or is only intended for framebuffers the size of the screen.

For this task - to leverage the GPU to store a destructively composited "stack" of 12 megapixel photos, and add an additional one on top at a specified opacity, repeatedly, while outputing the current contents of the stack scaled down to the screen - what is the best approach? Can I use an established framework/technique, or am I better of diving into OpenGL and Metal myself? I know the iPhone has this capability, I just need to figure out how to leverage it.

This is what I've got so far. Profiler tells me the rendering takes about 350ms, but I run out of memory if I increase to 20 pics. If I don't render after each loop, I can increase to about 60 pics before I run of out memory.

```
var stackBuffer: CIImage!
var stackRender: CGImage!
var uiImage: UIImage!

let glContext = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES3)
let context = CIContext(EAGLContext: glContext)

// Preload list of 10 test pics
var ciImageArray = Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: CIImage.emptyImage())
for i in 0...9 {
    uiImage = UIImage(named: String(i) + ".jpg")!
    ciImageArray[i] = CIImage(image: uiImage)!
}

// Put the first image in the buffer
stackBuffer = ciImageArray[0]
for i in 1...9 {

    // The next image will have an opacity of 1/n
    let topImage = ciImageArray[i]
    let alphaTop = topImage.imageByApplyingFilter(
        "CIColorMatrix", withInputParameters: [
        "inputAVector"  : CIVector(x:0, y:0, z:0, w:1/CGFloat(i + 1))
        ])

    // Layer the next image on top of the stack
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceOverCompositing")!
    filter.setValue(alphaTop, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(stackBuffer, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)

    // Render the result, and read back in
    stackRender = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, fromRect: stackBuffer.extent)
    stackBuffer = CIImage(CGImage: stackRender)
}

// Output result
uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: stackRender)
compositeView.image = uiImage
```